# I am unable to navigation using private functon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

**Navigation in flutter**

I want to navigate the Sign-in page to ListView Screen using the private method name is _navigateToListScreen but I am unable to od this I did not know the way how the private function call in the same class

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:signinproject/commen_widget/custome_elevate_button.dart';
    import 'list_view.dart';
    import 'list_view.dart';
    class SignInpage extends StatelessWidget {
    const SignInpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Sign In Screen', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
      elevation: 10,
        ),
      body: _buildContent(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
    );
  }

   Widget _buildContent() {
   return Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   //color: Colors.cyan,
   child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
           const Text(
           'Sign In',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
              child: Row(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Image.asset('Assets/Images/google.png'),
                const Text(
                  'Sign In with Google',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  child: Image.asset('Assets/Images/google.png'),
                  opacity: 0.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: 20.0,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
           const SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
            child: Row(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Image.asset('Assets/Images/facebook.png'),
                const Text(
                  'Sign In with Facebook',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  child: Image.asset('Assets/Images/facebook.png'),
                  opacity: 0.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: 20.0,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                'Sign in with Email',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              borderRadius: 20.0,
              onPressed: () {}),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8.00,
          ),
          const Text(
            'or',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              // fontFamily:f
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                'Get Anomous',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              color: Colors.limeAccent,
              borderRadius: 20.0,
              onPressed: () {}),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // SignInpage()._navigateToListScreen(context);
              // debugPrint('clicked me');
              //_navigateToListScreen();
            },
            child: const Text('Go to next Screen'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToListScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ListViewA(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the other screen that i want to move is code is following

//import 'dart:html';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewA extends StatelessWidget {
  //ListViewA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final activeuser = [
    'Tahir',
    'Naseem',
    'Tanveer',
    'Ahktar',
    'Hamayoun',
    'saima'
  ];

  ListViewA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('List view Screen'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(activeuser[index]),
            );
          },
          itemCount: activeuser.length,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you use `SignInpage()._navigateToListScreen(context);` ? Use this `_navigateToListScreen(context);`. The private function are available in the class which they are defined.

Comment: dear thanks for approaching but the problem still exists i do this but it compiler says me               _navigateToListScreen(context);
The argument type JsObject cannot be assigned to the parameter type Build context

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `context` to `_buildContent()` as well.

Here's the updated code.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:signinproject/commen_widget/custome_elevate_button.dart';
    import 'list_view.dart';
    import 'list_view.dart';
    class SignInpage extends StatelessWidget {
    const SignInpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Sign In Screen', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
      elevation: 10,
        ),
  //pass context
      body: _buildContent(context),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
    );
  }

   Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
   return Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   //color: Colors.cyan,
   child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
           const Text(
           'Sign In',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
              child: Row(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Image.asset('Assets/Images/google.png'),
                const Text(
                  'Sign In with Google',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  child: Image.asset('Assets/Images/google.png'),
                  opacity: 0.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: 20.0,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
           const SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
            child: Row(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Image.asset('Assets/Images/facebook.png'),
                const Text(
                  'Sign In with Facebook',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  child: Image.asset('Assets/Images/facebook.png'),
                  opacity: 0.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: 20.0,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 16.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                'Sign in with Email',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              borderRadius: 20.0,
              onPressed: () {}),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8.00,
          ),
          const Text(
            'or',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              // fontFamily:f
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          CustomeElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                'Get Anomous',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              color: Colors.limeAccent,
              borderRadius: 20.0,
              onPressed: () {}),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
                 //pass context
                _navigateToListScreen(context);
              // SignInpage()._navigateToListScreen(context);
              // debugPrint('clicked me');
              
            },
            child: const Text('Go to next Screen'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToListScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ListViewA(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `context` from your `builder` method in `MaterialRoute` .And use the code in your `onPressed` just like this

```
    onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => ListViewA()));
        }
```